# Why can't I simply overwrite < in a priority queue of pairs?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I'm aware that I can just do `priority_queue < P, vector<P>, Compare > queue;`, where `Compare` is a functor. But since the default comparator is `less<P>`, and it is the same as `<`, why doesn't it work when I do the following:

```
typedef pair<int, int> P;

bool operator<(const P& a, const P& b){   
    return (a.second < b.second);                                    
} 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int vec[] = {3, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2}; // just for testing
    priority_queue <P> queue;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
        queue.push(make_pair(i, vec[i]));   
    }
    cout << queue.top().second << endl; // returns 2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't that giving the expected result: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6aff4ef457a5bfd

Comment: I mean I wanted it to return 8, which is the greatest element in the queue.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue has an example of a custom comparer using a lambda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::pair` already has an [`operator<` declared inside namespace std](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp).

As this is in the same namespace as `pair`,  `std::less` will find that one first and then not look any further.

Comment: So I can't overwrite operators in std classes?

Comment: No, not really. The formal rule is that any overloaded operator must have at least one user defined type as a parameter. And you cannot create a new version of an operator that already exists.

Comment: @plethora You can anyway provide an appropriate functor class and pass that as template argument to the `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: @BoPersson check Alexey's answer... there seems to be a workaround... =]

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, I usually do that, but I was just curious why it didn't work this way. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @plethora - Yes that kind of works, but you are not allowed to add operators to namespace std. The code in the namespace can assume that you don't do that.

Comment: @BoPersson Hmm... I thought about maybe extending Pair and overloading the new class operator, but then I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41282964/1676020). So I guess the functor is still the best solution... =T

Comment: @BoPersson Sorry, wrong link, I meant [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/202340/1676020).

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> P;

struct comp {
    bool operator()(const P& a, const P& b){   
        return (a.second < b.second);                                    
    } 
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int vec[] = {3, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2}; // just for testing
    priority_queue <P, std::vector<P>, comp> queue;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
        queue.push(make_pair(i, vec[i]));   
    }
    cout << queue.top().second << endl; // returns 2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I usually do (mentioned it in the question), but I was just curious about why it didn't work this way. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace std {
    bool operator<(const P& a, const P& b) {
        return (a.second < b.second);
    }
}
```

and it work for me

UPD:
We can define own type for safeness:

```
class MyOwnPair: public std::pair<int,int>{};
typedef MyOwnPair P;
```

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. See [namespace.std] in the C++14 standard.

Comment: @user634175, Do you want to say that I cannot write my own specialization of std::vector<myOwnType> like this:
namespace std{ template<> class vector<myOwnType>{...}; }

Comment: I thought about maybe extending Pair and overloading the new class operator, but then I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41282964/1676020). So using functor is still the best solution?

Comment: @user634175 Sorry, wrong link, I meant [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/202340/1676020).

Comment: @plethora, yes, functor is a better solution, but you asked how to overload operator< and I answered you.

Comment: @AlexeySubbota Sure, sure, it was a good input. I just changed the chosen answer because it seems to be a bad practice, even though it was the exact thing I asked. I'm not sure how I should decide in these cases. Maybe add the "bad practice" alert to the answer?